# LabVIEW and Keithley 2635A - Unable to read data

Tags: timeout, labview, visa, gpib

I'm using LabVIEW and its VISA capabilities to control a Keithley 2635A source meter. Whenever I try to identify the device, it works just fine, both in reading and writing.

```
viWRITE(*IDN?) /* VISA subVI to send the command to the machine */
viREAD /* VISA subVI to read output */
```

However, as soon as I set the voltage (or current), it does so. Then I send the command to perform a measurement, but I'm not able to read that data, with the error

```
VISA:  (Hex 0xBFFF0015) Timeout expired before operation completed.
```

After that, I can not read the `*IDN?` output either anymore.

The source meter is connected to the PC via a National Instrument GPIB-USB-HS adaptor.

EDIT: I forgot to add, this happens in the VISA Interactive Control program as well.

Comment: Tip: Be sure to watch the front panel when you send commands or queries to see if there was an error. Also, you've said "set" and then "read". A "set" (command) wouldn't necessarily result in a response. Check the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, apparently the documentation is not very clear. What the `smua.measure.X()` (where `X` is the needed parameter) command does is, of course, writing the measurement outcome on a buffer. In order to read that buffer, however, the simple `viREAD[]` is not sufficient.

So basically the answer was to simply add a `print` command: this way I have

```
viWRITE[print(smua.measure.X())];
viREAD[]
```

And I don't have the error anymore. Not sure why such a command is needed, but that's that. Thank you all for your time answering me.

Comment: A SMU does have a measurement buffer but I'm not sure that `smua.measure.X()` would result in writing to it. But the key is that it doesn't write to the output (communications) buffer so viREAD gets nothing and times out. BTW—the language is Lua and `print` is a standard Lua function that they have wired to write to the output buffer.

Comment: @TomBlodget Great, thanks for the clarification. I think `smua.measure.X()` actually writes on a buffer, at least the documentation says that.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer once you figured it out! Can you edit the answer to include a link to the documentation as well?

Comment: Actually I used the PDF manual provided with the source meter, I wouldn't know where to find that.

Answer (score 0):

As @Tom Blodget mentions in the comments, the machine may not have any response to read after you set the voltage. The `*IDN?` string is **both command and query**. That is, you will *write* the command `*IDN?` and *read* the result. Some commands do not have any response to read. Here's a quick test to see if you should be reading from the instrument. The following code is in python; I made up the GPIB command to set voltage.

```
sm = SourceMonitor()
# Prints out IDN    
sm.query('*IDN?')

# Prints out current voltage (change this to your actual command)
sm.query('SOUR:VOLT?')

# Set a new voltage
sm.write('SOUR:VOLT 1V')

# Read the new voltage
sm.query('SOUR:VOLT?')
```

Note that question-marked GPIB commands and the `query` are used when you expect to get a response from the instrument. The instrument won't give a response for the `write` command. Query is a combination of `write(...)` and `read(...)`. If you're using LabView, you may have to write the write and read separately.

If you **need** verification that the machine received your instruction and acted on it, most instruments have the following common commands:

- `*OPC?` query to see if the operation is complete
- `SYST:ERR?` query to see if any error was generated
- Add a question mark `?` to the end of the GPIB command used to set the voltage

Comment: I should have been more clear, sorry. What I meant was that, after I send the command to set the voltage, I send another `write` command to request a measurement and then use `read` to retrieve that measurement.

As for the `*IDN?` command, when I send it to the machine I have no feedback, I still have to send a `read` signal.
I'll edit this in the post as well.

Comment: I see... If your dataset is large, it may take a long time to read from the instrument. For some of my GPIB connections, I need to specify longer timeout values when reading the result of a test. Can you post a minimal set of commands (with voltage and `*IDN?`) that gives you the timeout error?

Comment: The set of commands is actually pretty basic itself. Calling `viWRITE` and `viREAD`, respectively, the VISA subVIs to write and read, and putting into square brackets the string input, my VI is `viWRITE[*IDN?]; viREAD[]; viWRITE[smua.output.levelv = 0.1]; viWRITE[smua.measure.v()]; viREAD[]`. The timeout occurs at the last read command. The read commands all are fed a large enough buffer

Comment: Yes, your commands look fine to me too. Do you know what the timeout length is on your read command? Even if the buffer is big, the read can fail if there's not enough time to read the data across the GPIB bus.

Comment: Found the issue. It was a mere `print` command missing, apparently. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad you found it! I'll leave my answer here in case someone new to GPIB communication needs to know the difference between `write`, `read`, and `query`.